# Vagrantで起動したUbuntu14.04でpublic_networkを使用するとeth0がデフォルトゲートウェイの設定に失敗する

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, network, virtualbox

**環境**
Vagrant: 2.1.1
VirtualBox: 5.2.12
ホスト: Windows10
ゲスト: Ubuntu14.04

**現象が発生した要因**
VM作成直後はこの現象は発生していなかった。apt-get等でパッケージの追加等を色々行っていると、いつのまにか発生するようになった？別の仮想マシン(Ubuntu16.04)では同様の設定でも現象は発生していない。

**詳細**

`デフォルトゲートウェイの設定に失敗する`とは下記の症状を指します。

`route`コマンドでdefaultが表示されない。eth0がNAT, eth1がホストオンリーアダプタ(private_network), eth2がブリッジアダプタ(public_network)です。

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ route
カーネルIP経路テーブル
受信先サイト    ゲートウェイ    ネットマスク   フラグ Metric Ref 使用数 インタフェース
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.28.128.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.254.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

本来期待する結果は下記の通りです。

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ route 
カーネルIP経路テーブル 
受信先サイト    ゲートウェイ    ネットマスク   フラグ Metric Ref 使用数 インタフェース
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.28.128.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.254.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Vagrantfileでは下記のように設定しています。

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

起動後、手動でeth0を再起動させると、defaultが表示されるようになります。

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
vagrant@vagrant:~$ route 
カーネルIP経路テーブル 
受信先サイト    ゲートウェイ    ネットマスク   フラグ Metric Ref 使用数 インタフェース
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.28.128.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.254.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`のpost-upの行をコメントアウトし、VirtualBoxから直接起動した場合もdefaultが表示されます。 (defaultがeth2になっていますが)

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
    # post-up ip route del default dev $IFACE || true
#VAGRANT-END

vagrant@vagrant:~$ route
カーネルIP経路テーブル
受信先サイト    ゲートウェイ    ネットマスク   フラグ Metric Ref 使用数 インタフェース
default         192.168.254.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.28.128.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.254.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

何か原因や、確認すべきポイントはわからないでしょうか？

**追記**
今回はデフォルトゲートウェイはethNのどれでもよかったので、public_networkの設定を下記のようにすることで、eth2がデフォルトゲートウェイとして設定されるようになりました。

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", type: "dhcp", use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
end
```

ただ、この質問で知りたいのは、なぜeth0が自動的にデフォルトゲートウェイとして設定されないのか、です。
情報をお持ちの方は引き続きよろしくお願いします。

**@cubickさんのコメントを受けて追記**

下記の通り、public_networkを使用した場合だけ現象が発生します。

**成功**

- NATのみ
- NAT + private_network

**失敗**

- NAT + public_network
- NAT + private_network + public_network

Comment: ゲストOS側で複数のNICがある状態のようですが、すべて使用するのでしょうか？問題切り分けのため、不要なものはできるだけ無効にしておいた方がよい気がします。